# Copying file from server is slow but is fast when copying to server

Tags: windows, networking, performance, ethernet, file-transfer

I have a Samsung 970 Evo+ in the built-in M.2 slot of the HP 290-p0043w and have a gigabit network cable connection directly between it and an gigabit port on an Asus X99 Deluxe motherboard. Both systems are running Windows 10.

I noticed that when I copy a large file from the Asus to the HP, I get consistent 113 MBps (904 Mbps) transfer speeds, as I would expect from a gigabit connection. However, when I copy a large file from the HP to the Asus, I only get 69-73 MBps (552-584 Mbps) on average. This is not what I would expect, this is significantly slower than gigabit.

The Asus machine has a Samsung 860 Pro SATA SSD as its target drive, while the HP has the Samsung 970 Evo+ its target drive. I have tried multiple Cat 6 Ethernet cables to connect the two machines and get the same results with both, so it’s not the cable. I also tried copying from the boot HDD that came with the HP in place of the 970 Evo+ and get very similar results (113 MBps when writing to the HP’s HDD from the Asus SSD, and 73 MBps when writing from the HP’s HDD to the Asus SSD). So clearly it is network limited somehow. It’s not the drives, it’s not the cable, and it’s not the M2 interface the 970 Evo+ is hooked into since I get the same results with the HDD. Same results after restarting both computers.

For all of these tests, the copy is initiated through Windows File Explorer from the Asus machine. The folders are shared using Windows’ default drive sharing feature (right click a drive → sharing → advanced sharing → network).

My guess is it has something to do with the network adapter. In device manager, if I go to Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, I see “Transmit Buffers” having a value of 128 (I can’t make it higher) and receive buffers of 512 (also can’t make it higher). I have Speed and Duplex set to “1.0 Gbps Full Duplex.” I’m not sure what these values mean and if they are responsible for the slower speeds when transferring from the HP to the Asus.

Considering all of this, does anybody know what is wrong here or what I can do to fix it? Why is the transfer speed from the HP to the Asus so much slower than the other way around?

Edit: I ran iperf as suggested:

```
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\iperf-3.1.3-win64> .\iperf3.exe -c HP-HOSTNAME -p 577
Connecting to host HP-HOSTNAME, port 577
[  4] local fe80::.........:4609 port 58675 connected to fe80::.......:f560 port 577
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   112 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   111 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   112 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   936 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   936 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\iperf-3.1.3-win64> .\iperf3.exe -s -p 577
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 577
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from fe80::.......:f560, port 49676
[  5] local fe80::.........:4609 port 577 connected to fe80::1d0:6eda:a58:f560 port 49677
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  71.3 MBytes   598 Mbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  71.3 MBytes   598 Mbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  72.1 MBytes   605 Mbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  72.0 MBytes   604 Mbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  72.2 MBytes   606 Mbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  72.1 MBytes   605 Mbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  72.2 MBytes   605 Mbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  72.1 MBytes   605 Mbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  71.6 MBytes   600 Mbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  71.4 MBytes   599 Mbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-10.01  sec  1023 KBytes   591 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-10.01  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-10.01  sec   719 MBytes   602 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

As you can see, it is the exact same result.

Comment: Have you tried measuring _separately_ the network speed (using iperf3 or similar) and the disk write speed (using crystaldiskmark or similar)? Also, *why* do you have Speed and Duplex configured manually?

Comment: @user1686, please see my edit, I ran iperf as you suggested. Same issue.